# Rendered image in viewport not showing in compositing tab?

Tags: rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I'm following a tutorial and seem to have the nodes set up correctly but the viewport in the background won't appear, what could be going wrong here? [image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Did you Render your scene (F12) before you move to the compositing tab?

Answer (score 1):

Just press this little icon here:

[image]

it is right beside the "view layer" text

[image]

Comment: This was the answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ChronicPinkEye : you are welcome. So please check the checkmark left to my answer, because this is the „official“ way to show that this is the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the <kbd>Backdrop</kbd> option, shown in the screenshot with the right-marker. And also link an output, <kbd>Viewer</kbd> node to your input, Render Layer node, shown with the left-marker in the screenshot.

This should display the rendered image in the background of your compositing editor which allows quick tweaking of the image without needing to switch editors.

[image]